# Apache Commons Exec produces too many quotes for arguments containing spaces?

Tags: java, apache-commons-exec

Either there is a bug in Apache Commons Exec, or I am using the API wrong, but when I use the `CommandLine` class to add a argument that contains spaces, some quotes are added and are then part of the argument that is given.

For example: When I call `java "what version"` I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: what version`, and when I call `java "\"what version\""` (which contains escaped quotes, that are part of the command line argument itself), I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: "what version"`.

So the following test fails, because as you can see in the last line, Apache Exec is producing the latter version where it should have produced the first version:

```
@Test
public void testArgumentQuoting() throws Exception {
    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(out, out);
    executor.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);
    CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine("java");
    cmdLine.addArgument("what version");
    executor.execute(cmdLine, resultHandler);
    resultHandler.waitFor();
    String resultPattern = "Exception in thread \"main\" java\\.lang\\.NoClassDefFoundError: ([\\w \"]+)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(resultPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(out.toString());
    Assert.assertTrue(matcher.find());
    // Note: Result should be <what version> and NOT <"what version">!
    Assert.assertEquals("what version", matcher.group(1));
}
```

Now I want to know:

- Is this a bug?
- If so: Is there a way to circumvent this problem (a workaround)?
- If not: What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I am trying to execute a process which I think fewest people will have on their machine. So I am using `java` instead as this command should be available on all machines where people develop Java. My point is that the wrong runtime argument is passed to the external process, containing escaped quotes, which it shouldn't.

Edit: I made this a filed bug for commons exec at [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/EXEC-54?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=12992912#comment-12992912).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a [real bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/EXEC-54?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=12992912#comment-12992912) in Apache Commons Exec, which to date has not been fixed.

Comment: Unbelievable that this hasn't been fixed--does no one use commons-exec with arguments that actually need quoting?

Comment: @Miles commons-exec is awful when it comes to quotes, and no one will fix it. I'm also baffled why no one uses commons-exec, given the lack of alternatives. Does everyone really RYO broken ProcessBuilder wrappers? Speaking of which, why wasn't ProcessBuilder designed correctly in the first place? Maybe no one use Java to spawn processes?

Answer (score 7):

Apache common exec has `addArgument` method with `handleQuoting` flag.
If it's turned on, then it wraps arguments in quotation marks.

By default it's turned on

```
public CommandLine addArgument(final String argument, boolean handleQuoting)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try the next example it works for me :

```
  CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine("mco");
  cmdLine.addArgument("shellcmd" );
  cmdLine.addArguments( puppetAgents.split(" ") );
  cmdLine.addArgument("-t");
  cmdLine.addArgument(timeout);
  // When writing a command with space use double "
  cmdLine.addArgument("\"\"puppet agent -t\"\"",false);
```

Answer (score 0):

What class are you trying to execute?  You're not specifying exactly what you want Java to execute.  That needs to be your second argument.

In other words, if you're trying to run com.mycompany.MyExecutable, your code should look like this:

```
CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine("java com.mycompany.MyExecutable");
```

You can either append arguments after the CommandLine object is created.

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering. Actually I am not trying to execute a Java class but a completely different process. But since this is very specific, I wouldn't want to write a test case for that, as I don't think anybody has this on his machine. On the other hand, everybody talking about Java has `java` installed on his machine, hence this test case...

Answer (score 0):

How about trying it this way as in the [tutorial](http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html), to see if that makes a difference?

```
...
String line = "java what version";
CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(line);
executor.execute(cmdLine, resultHandler);
...
```

Comment: This does not work at all, because Apache Commons Exec rightly treats the two words as separate arguments, because they are separated by a space. But in my case, I need an single argument that contains spaces... But anyway, thanks for the input.