# Running command with with space argument value with apache command line

Tags: java, git, apache, command

I'm using apache command line library and I want to execute from java program

```
git stash list --format=%gd:%at:%B --grep="some text with space"
```

this is the code
    commandLine.addArgument( "--grep=\"" + filter+"\"", false);
it is run on windows without any problem but on linux does not.
If i execute the command from terminal it is execute correctly

I also tried to let apache library to put quoting

```
commandLine.addArgument( "--grep=" + filter);
```

but i get

```
fatal: bad revision '"--grep=text message"'
```

Answer (score 1):

While there is a [bug around quotes managements in Common Exec](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/EXEC-54), this [answers suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24137668/6309):

```
// When writing a command with space use double "
cmdLine.addArgument(--grep=\"\"" + filter+"\"\"", false"\"\"",false);
```