# Java Rsync Escape Spaces

Tags: java, escaping, command-line-interface, rsync, apache-commons-exec

I am trying to run rsync from a jar.  When the source path has no spaces it all works fine, but when the source path has a space in it, it fails.  I have tried various methods for escaping the spaces, as per the man pages, such as source.replaceAll("\s", "\\ ") or source.replaceAll("\s", "?"), but to no avail.

When I output the command that is run and then run the exact same command from the command line, it all works.  I can't see what I am doing wrong

My code is as follows:

RsyncCommandLine class

```
public class RsyncCommandLine {

    /** Logger */
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(RsyncCommandLine.class);

    private CommandLine commandLine = null;

    public String startRsync(String source, String destination) throws IOException {
        commandLine = createCommandLine(source, destination);

        CommandLineExecutorHelper helper = new CommandLineExecutorHelper();
        CommandLineLogOutputStream outputStream = helper.executeCommandLine(commandLine);
        validateResponse(outputStream);
        return convertLinesToString(outputStream.getLines());
    }

    private void validateResponse(CommandLineLogOutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        if (outputStream == null) {
            logger.error("outputStream  is not valid");
            throw new IOException("Unable to use rsync. ");
        } else if (outputStream.getExitCode() != 0) {
            logger.error("Exit code: " + outputStream.getExitCode());
            logger.error("Validate Response failed " + outputStream.getLines());
            String errorMessage = exitCodeToErrorMessage(outputStream.getExitCode());
            throw new IOException("Error with request. " + errorMessage);
        } else if (outputStream.getLines() == null || outputStream.getLines().isEmpty()) {
            logger.error("Rsync result: " + outputStream.getLines());
            String errorMessage = "Unable to rsync. ";

            throw new IOException(errorMessage);

        }
    }

    private String exitCodeToErrorMessage(int exitCode) {
        String errorMessage = null;
        switch (exitCode) {
            case 0: errorMessage="Success."; break;
            case 1: errorMessage="Syntax or usage error."; break;
            case 2: errorMessage="Protocol incompatibility."; break;
            case 3: errorMessage="Errors selecting input/output files, dirs."; break;
            case 4: errorMessage="Requested action not supported: an attempt was made to manipulate 64-bit files on a platform that cannot support them; or an option was specified that is supported by the client and not by the server."; break;
            case 5: errorMessage="Error starting client-server protocol."; break;
            case 6: errorMessage="Daemon unable to append to log-file."; break;
            case 10: errorMessage="Error in socket I/O."; break;
            case 11: errorMessage="Error in file I/O."; break;
            case 12: errorMessage="Error in rsync protocol data stream."; break;
            case 13: errorMessage="Errors with program diagnostics."; break;
            case 14: errorMessage="Error in IPC code."; break;
            case 20: errorMessage="Received SIGUSR1 or SIGINT."; break;
            case 21: errorMessage="Some error returned by waitpid()."; break;
            case 22: errorMessage="Error allocating core memory buffers."; break;
            case 23: errorMessage="Partial transfer due to error."; break;
            case 24: errorMessage="Partial transfer due to vanished source files."; break;
            case 25: errorMessage="The --max-delete limit stopped deletions."; break;
            case 30: errorMessage="Timeout in data send/receive."; break;
            case 35: errorMessage="Timeout waiting for daemon connection."; break;
            default: errorMessage="Unrecognised error code.";
        }
        return errorMessage;
    }


    protected String convertLinesToString(List<String> lines) {
        String result = null;

        if (lines != null && !lines.isEmpty()) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line : lines) {
                builder.append(line).append(" ");
            }
            result = builder.toString().trim();
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected CommandLine createCommandLine(String source, String destination) {
        // rsync -rtvuch <source> <destination>

        commandLine = new CommandLine("rsync");
        commandLine.addArgument("-rtvuch");

        String escapedSource = source.trim().replaceAll("\\s", "\\\\ ");
        String escapedDestination = destination.trim().replaceAll("\\s", "\\\\ ");
        commandLine.addArgument(source);
        commandLine.addArgument(escapedDestination);

        logger.debug("escapedSource " + escapedSource);
        logger.debug("escapedDestination " + escapedDestination);

        return commandLine;
    }

}
```

CommandLineExecutorHelper class -

```
public class CommandLineExecutorHelper {

    /** Logger */
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CommandLineExecutorHelper.class);

    private DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();

    private ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(10000);

    private DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();


    public CommandLineExecutorHelper() {
        executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);
    }

    public CommandLineLogOutputStream executeCommandLine(CommandLine commandLine) {
        CommandLineLogOutputStream outputStream = new CommandLineLogOutputStream();
        PumpStreamHandler pumpStreamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(outputStream);
        executor.setStreamHandler(pumpStreamHandler);
        try {
            executor.execute(commandLine, resultHandler);

            resultHandler.waitFor();
            outputStream.setExitCode(resultHandler.getExitValue());
            logger.debug("\n\ncommandLine " + commandLine);
            logger.debug("exit code " + resultHandler.getExitValue());
            logger.debug("output " + outputStream.getLines());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            outputStream.addErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
            logger.error("executeCommandLine " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExecuteException e) {
            outputStream.addErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
            logger.error("executeCommandLine " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            outputStream.addErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
            logger.error("executeCommandLine " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
        }

        return outputStream;
    }
}
```

CommnadLineOutputStream class -

```
public class CommandLineLogOutputStream extends LogOutputStream {
    private int exitCode = -1;

    private final List<String> lines = new LinkedList<>();

    private StringBuilder errorMessages = new StringBuilder();


    /**
     * @return the exitCode
     */
    public int getExitCode() {
        return exitCode;
    }

    /**
     * @param exitCode the exitCode to set
     */
    public void setExitCode(int exitCode) {
        this.exitCode = exitCode;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lines
     */
    public List<String> getLines() {
        return lines;
    }



    /**
     * @return the errorMessages
     */
    public StringBuilder getErrorMessages() {
        return errorMessages;
    }

    /**
     * @param errorMessages the errorMessages to set
     */
    public void setErrorMessages(StringBuilder errorMessages) {
        this.errorMessages = errorMessages;
    }

    public void addErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessages.append(errorMessage);
    }


    @Override
    protected void processLine(String line, int logLevel) {
        lines.add(line);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("CommandLineLogOutputStream [exitCode=").append(exitCode).append(", lines=").append(lines).append(", errorMessages=").append(errorMessages).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

So when I run my jar without a space it is successful:

```
java -jar myjar.jar -source "/var/source"
```

output command is:

```
commandLine [rsync, -rtvuch, "/var/source", /var/dest]
```

When I run the same jar against a path with spaces:

```
java -jar myjar.jar -source "/var/source with spaces"
```

I get the following error message:

```
Exit code: 23
Validate Response failed [building file list ... donersync: link_stat "/Users/karen/"/var/source with spaces"" failed: No such file or directory (2), building file list ... donersync: link_stat "/Users/karen/"/var/source with spaces"" failed: No such file or directory (2), , sent 21 bytes  received 20 bytes  82.00 bytes/sec, total size is 0  speedup is 0.00, rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]]
Unable to rsync Error with request. Partial transfer due to error.
```

The destination path is picked up from a file open dialog.

Comment: What O/S are you using?

Comment: I am running it on a mac but will need it to run on linux and windows as well.  I am currently just running it from the command line but will need to run it from a script either bash, perl, vbscript or applescript.  Its a part of integrating 2 products together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After various input I decided to use the ProcessBuilder instead.  I then got it working using the following code:

```
public class RsyncCommandLine {

    /** Logger */
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(RsyncCommandLine.class);


    public String startRsync(String source, String destination) throws IOException {
        List<String> commands = createCommandLine(source, destination);
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        Integer exitCode = null;
        try {
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands).redirectErrorStream(true);

            final Process process = processBuilder.start();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                lines.add(line);
            }
            // Allow process to run up to 60 seconds
            process.waitFor(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            // Get exit code from process
            exitCode = process.exitValue();
            //Convert exit code to meaningful statement
            String exitMessage = exitCodeToErrorMessage(exitCode);               
            lines.add(exitMessage);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex);
        }

        return convertLinesToString(lines);
    }


    private String exitCodeToErrorMessage(Integer exitCode) {
        String errorMessage = null;
        switch (exitCode) {
        case 0:
            errorMessage = "Success.";
            break;
        case 1:
            errorMessage = "Syntax or usage error.";
            break;
        case 2:
            errorMessage = "Protocol incompatibility.";
            break;
        case 3:
            errorMessage = "Errors selecting input/output files, dirs.";
            break;
        case 4:
            errorMessage = "Requested action not supported: an attempt was made to manipulate 64-bit files on a platform that cannot support them; or an option was specified that is supported by the client and not by the server.";
            break;
        case 5:
            errorMessage = "Error starting client-server protocol.";
            break;
        case 6:
            errorMessage = "Daemon unable to append to log-file.";
            break;
        case 10:
            errorMessage = "Error in socket I/O.";
            break;
        case 11:
            errorMessage = "Error in file I/O.";
            break;
        case 12:
            errorMessage = "Error in rsync protocol data stream.";
            break;
        case 13:
            errorMessage = "Errors with program diagnostics.";
            break;
        case 14:
            errorMessage = "Error in IPC code.";
            break;
        case 20:
            errorMessage = "Received SIGUSR1 or SIGINT.";
            break;
        case 21:
            errorMessage = "Some error returned by waitpid().";
            break;
        case 22:
            errorMessage = "Error allocating core memory buffers.";
            break;
        case 23:
            errorMessage = "Partial transfer due to error.";
            break;
        case 24:
            errorMessage = "Partial transfer due to vanished source files.";
            break;
        case 25:
            errorMessage = "The --max-delete limit stopped deletions.";
            break;
        case 30:
            errorMessage = "Timeout in data send/receive.";
            break;
        case 35:
            errorMessage = "Timeout waiting for daemon connection.";
            break;
        default:
            errorMessage = "Unrecognised error code.";
        }
        return errorMessage;
    }

    protected String convertLinesToString(List<String> lines) {
        String result = null;

        if (lines != null && !lines.isEmpty()) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line : lines) {
                builder.append(line).append(" ");
            }
            result = builder.toString().trim();
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected List<String> createCommandLine(String source, String destination) {
        // rsync -rtvuch <source> <destination>
        List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();

        commands.add("rsync");
        commands.add("-rtvuch");

        String escapedSource = source.trim();
        String escapedDestination = destination.trim();

        commands.add(escapedSource);
        commands.add(escapedDestination);
        logger.debug("escapedSource " + escapedSource);
        logger.debug("escapedDestination " + escapedDestination);

        return commands;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think this code risks deadlock if the process writes more than one O/S pipe buffer full of output: the process will block waiting for its `stdout` to be read, but your code will not read until after the process has exited. You need to either read `stdout` on a separate thread or read until exit, rather than read after exit.

Comment: Thanks @Rich I will rewrite it accordingly and edit the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257546/running-command-with-with-space-argument-value-with-apache-command-line)?

> While there is a [bug around quotes managements in Common Exec](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/EXEC-54),
>   this [answers suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24137668/6309):
>
> ```
> // When writing a command with space use double "
> cmdLine.addArgument(--grep=\"\"" + filter+"\"\"", false"\"\"",false);
> ```

Comment: thanks for your answer but double quoting twice and adding false to addArgument method also didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Apache Commons Exec has a bug here and cannot properly handle arguments with spaces in them. This open bug (that m4gic linked to) has several contradictory explanations and workarounds: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/EXEC-54

I would suggest rewriting your code to use Java's built in "[Runtime.exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[]))" function, with the `String[]` form of the command-line (or the equivalent `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` API), to bypass any shell escaping and quoting issues entirely.

You will have to manually deal with a few technical details that Apache Commons Exec hides from you, such as potential i/o deadlock between stdout and stderr, but it is quite possible to deal with those whereas I don't think it is possible to get Apache to do what you want here. The [Apache Commons Exec intr](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html)o discusses some of these issues. You should be able to find some example code using `Runtime.exec` or `ProcessBuilder` on the internet. GL!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up using ProcessBuilder instead as shown in my answer.

Comment: Sounds good to me. I think you have still run into one of the sharp edges that Apache Commons Exec was designed to hide. I have commented on your other answer. It is a shame that ACE is bugged, but I think it is obsolete now that Java has ProcessBuilder built in.